# BigCommerce API. How to connect using WInHTTP

Tags: winhttp, bigcommerce

How can I connect to BigCommerce API using WinHTTP?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want to take a look at the sample code on MSDN. At this time, Bigcommerce does not have .NET based client libraries.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383147(v=vs.85).aspx

In the example shown, you can replace [authenticationSite] with store_url, User name and Password with your API credentials (eg. admin, apikey)

Hope this helps.